# angular2-jwt : useFactory directive being ignored

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

I'm struggling to integrate the angular2-jwt package. I've written the following function with custom configuration options

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { provideAuth, AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {

    return new AuthHttp( new AuthConfig({
        noTokenScheme: true,
        tokenGetter: (() => JSON.parse(     localStorage.getItem('access_token') ) ),
        globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json'}],
    }), this.http, this.options); 
}
```

and inside my module definition I have included the lines

```
providers: [
    ...,
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }        
],
```

but when I try to use AuthHttp inside a service it appears to ignore my factory method and returns a default implementation:

import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class SsoService {

```
constructor (
    private authHttp: AuthHttp,
) {}
```

Is my module configuration correct? Have I missed something simple

Answer (score 2):

For anybody else I changed the module to use an inline solution instead of the factory class to read as follows:

```
  providers: [
      ...
      AuthHttp,
      provideAuth({
          noTokenScheme: true,
          tokenGetter: (() => JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('access_token') ) ),
          globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json'}],
      })      
  ],
```